# How to setup a override registration in Structuremap 4.4

Tags: c#, structuremap4

So I have container in which i add a registry that defines a default type for a class.

```
TestRegistry : Registry{
    For<Foo>.Use<Foo>();
}
```

this registry is added at the start of a web service during initialization of the application.  directly after adding my all my registries used for the application I need to override the registration of the `Foo` class. So:

```
Container.Instance.Configure(x => 
{
    x.AddRegistry<TestRegistry>();
    var fooInstance = new Foo();
    x.For<Foo>.Use(fooInstance);
}
```

When i go to retrieve this instance from my container

```
var fromContainer = Container.Instance.GetInstance<Foo>();
```

i am now getting back `null`.  if I use get all instances:

```
var fromContainer = Container.Instance.GetAllInstances<Foo>();
```

I get back two results.  One for each registration.  This makes sense.

However, if i try to clear the registration during the second registration:

```
Container.Instance.Configure(x => 
{
    x.AddRegistry<TestRegistry>();
    var fooInstance = new Foo();
    x.For<Foo>.ClearAll().Use(fooInstance);
}
var fromContainer = Container.Instance.GetInstance<Foo>();
```

This still returns `null`.  I seem to be missing something here.  I would expect this to clear out all registrations of `Foo` and use the instance that i registered last.

Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I found my answer.  It looks like only the `Container.Instance` does not actually contain the definition until the configuration method is complete.  This means that in order to override the implementation you will need to call `Container.Instance.Configure()` a second time with the override.  Once i did this it started to work as expected.

Comment: Faced the same issue on v.4 of StructureMap. What I found was replacing x.AddRegistry by x.IncludeRegistry fixed the problem